# How do I install the Sphinx Search PHP API for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, sphinx

I have searched everywhere it seems. I am trying to install it from the terminal.

PHP is throwing an error stating SphinxClient() object cannot be found. So, I know it does not come built-in with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Just add sphinxapi.php to your project and include it like this:

```
include('sphinxapi.php');
```

or this:

```
require('sphinxapi.php')
```

You can find the source code here https://github.com/sphinxsearch/sphinx/blob/master/api/sphinxapi.php

Alternatively if you have installed Sphinx (or Manticoresearch) from a package the library can be found here /usr/share/sphinx/api/sphinxapi.php

If you want a PECL module, not the source code, you can install it from here https://pecl.php.net/package/sphinx , but be aware that atm (Feb 2018) that pecl module is very outdated and may not work well with newer Sphinx/Manticoresearch binaries. Most likely it won't.

P.S. I'd recommend to use SphinxQL instead which doesn't require SphinxClient() and has wider range of functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Next question. So, for some reason, pho is throwing an error stating the mysqli object cannot be found. This should not be happening because php7+ already has mysqli includes. Why is this happening?

Comment: @Hayden It's difficult to answer this question w/o having the code to look at. Can you try to simplify your code to the degree of just few calls and show the example?

Comment: @Hayden perhaps you have the same issue as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876610/how-do-i-use-sphinx-search-with-php (see my reply)

Comment: There is the API and then there is SphinxQL, to my knowledge. I gave up on the API, could not get the extension to work.